# Binary logarithm in O(1) time (operating on registers x86 or SIMD) without shifting?

Tags: assembly, x86, sse, mmx, binary-log

I wanted to see if there is a method for finding the [binary log](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_logarithm) of a number. Say you have the number 4 then the power to which you raise two to get four is 2.

I know this is possible with shifting and counting but that uses `O(N)` operations. Is there some way to get `O(1)` for any `n` where `x = 2^n`?

I want to find `n` here knowing `x` in one operation or `O(1)`.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/994709/253056

Comment: Yeah I figured out the assembler part but only after the answer on this thread. I had no idea `BSR` existed. Thx for the note though.

Comment: In SIMD, you can cast to float and extract the exponent.

Comment: for the HW angle, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368680/count-leading-zero-in-single-cycle-datapath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've specified x86, it sounds like you want the `BSR` (bit-scan reverse) opcode, which reports the position of the most-significant set bit.

[*FYI: big-O notation refers to asymptotic complexity (i.e. as N -> infinity); it doesn't make much sense if N has a finite limit (32 or 64 in this case).*]

Comment: `BSR` is an x86 instruction. I'll have to look it up, thanks for the `FYI`. I hardly ever use this stuff, only when I get creative.

Comment: Depending on what compiler you are using there will most likely be an intrinsic you can use for this to save you writing asm - certainly both gcc and MSVC have such intrinsics (albeit with different names).

Comment: @Paul R I'm using GCC, I looked all over the intrinsics for this and I can't find anything that would work similar to `BSR`. Let me know if you think of something.

Comment: For gcc it's `__builtin_clz` (where `clz` stands for Count Leading Zeroes). See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13476983/find-first-1-in-binary-number/13477081#13477081) for more details for gcc and MSVC.

Comment: @PaulR good ref, "Count leading zeroes" is what gets you this on a lot of architectures other than x86. See the table on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_first_set for other instruction sets.

Comment: @FrankH: yes, unfortunately it goes by several different names: CLZ, FFS, BSR, etc, but I tend to think of it as CLZ.

Comment: On a slightly different angle ... newer (post-Nehalem Intel / post-Barcelona AMD) x86 CPUs actually have `lzcnt` to _shortcut_ the need to post-process `bsr` results (subtract from number of bits in operand and do zero detection).